# O que é o operador lógico "XOR" em PHP? Quando usa-lo? O que ele faz?

Tags: php

Gostaria de saber o que é esse operador `XOR`? Quando usa-lo? E o que ele faz em PHP?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`XOR` é o operador de OU EXCLUSIVO. Ele é utilizado quando você quer verificar a veracidade de uma expressão OU outra, exclusivamente.

Exemplo: Eu tenho 2 horas por semana para estudar ou PHP ou JAVA.

Neste caso, estamos falando em operador exclusivo. Ou um ou outro, nunca ambos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Veja que se ambos são falsos ou ambos são verdadeiros, o comparador XOR retornará falso. Ele só retornará verdadeiro mediante exclusivamente uma das condições ser verdadeira.

Answer (score 4):

`xor` é um operador lógico como `or` e `and`. Ele retorna verdadeiro se os dois operandos forem diferentes, e falso se os dois forem iguais, tanto verdadeiro como falso.

Um exemplo prático é quando você precisa que um campo precise ser selecionado, mas nunca dois ao mesmo tempo, como no caso do sexo: O usuário precisa selecionar um sexo, e nunca  mais de um <sub>(pelo menos na maioria dos casos)</sub>. Um exemplo em PHP:

```
<?php
  $masculino = true;
  $feminino  = false;

  if ($masculino xor $feminino) {
    print("Correto! Um sexo foi escolhido");
  } else {
    print("ERRO! Nenhum ou ambos sexos foram escolhidos.");
  }
```

Veja funcionando no [IDEONE](http://ideone.com/bpD2Ju).