# Como trocar valores de duas variáveis sem usar uma terceira em php

Tags: php, variáveis, funções, otimização

Minha pergunta é bem objetiva.
Preciso trocar valores de duas variáveis sem usar uma terceira em php.
*OBS: Usar vetor/matriz não é uma opção.*

Pesquisando encontrei uma solução em `linguagem c` [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16373/como-trocar-o-valor-entre-duas-variaveis-sem-utilizar-variavel-auxiliar), porém não consegui passar pro `php`.
Também encontrei [essa solução](http://www.htmlstaff.org/ver.php?id=23452), entretanto está acontecendo um **bug**  bem peculiar.

Este é meu código:

```
        $change_provider = "Desenvolvimento Web";
        $change_receiver = "SEO(Search Engine Optimization)";

        $change_provider ^= $change_receiver ^= $change_provider ^= $change_receiver;

        print_r($change_provider); //string(19) "SEO(Search Engine O" 
        print_r($change_receiver); //string(19) "Desenvolvimento Web"
```

Percebam que minha saída está faltando alguns caracteres no final. Como resolver este problema ?
Agradeço quem puder ajudar.

Comment: Vi se passou o site solução, e apenas numero para fazer binario, se esta tentado string com XOR-Assignment, e veja codigo http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5126616/xor-operation-with-two-strings-in-java

Comment: Essas soluções estão em Java. Eles utilizam muitas bibliotecas nativas para funcionar.

Comment: Sim, Java e não entende a linguagem? você pode trocar informação para seu codigo PHP PDO

Comment: Veja se resolve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18356437/swap-two-variables-value-without-using-third-variable-in-php

Comment: Acho encontrei 1 português esta explicado bem e entre http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/47897/o-que-%C3%A9-o-operador-l%C3%B3gico-xor-em-php-quando-usa-lo-o-que-ele-faz

Comment: @KingRider Eu teria que duplicar a biblioteca nativa do java para conseguir fazer usando sua lógica. Quanto a outra solução é a mesma que estou usando e não esta dado certo usando string.

Comment: @PapaCharlie Na resposta mais bem votada ele usa array para fazer a troca e isso não é uma opção no meu caso. Nas demais ele utiliza a mesma solução que encontrei e não se aplica pra string.

Comment: Como não é uma opção? Veja um exemplo com string: http://ideone.com/ekQM7Q, usar array é apenas para obter a ordem inversa com `list`.

Comment: @RicardoMota segue demonstração: http://ideone.com/d0VFZL - sobre o fato de dizer que array não se aplica no seu caso, eu acho improvável, mas quando for assim, compensa por na pergunta qual é a razão. Pode ser simplesmente falta de usar da maneira mais adequada, ou talvez as respostas atendam melhor se o problema ficar mais claro. Se puder explicar a razão do array não servir, dá pra pensar em alternativas.

Comment: Obrigado pelas orientações e a solução @Bacco. O intuito é inteiramente acadêmico, na próxima vou lembrar de além de detalhar as especificações dizer o porquê destas.

Comment: Isso ajuda a postarmos respostas que vão de encontro com o problema. No caso, não vejo nenhuma maneira realmente boa de fazer sem uma terceira variável ou array, inclusive pq, lembrando que PHP armazena referencias (HLL) para os valores, tanto array quanto 3a variável são soluçõe "baratas", que não envolvem realocação de memória com os valores. Talvez até dê pra atender a premissa da pergunta sem variável ou array, mas a solução provavelmente seria muito mais custosa e complexa.

Answer (score 4):

Basicamente isso:

```
list( $a, $b ) = array( $b, $a );
```

Nas versões mais novas:

```
list( $a, $b ) = [ $b, $a ];
```

Importante notar que tanto as soluções acima, como o uso de uma terceira variável, são eficazes no sentido de não dependerem de realocação de memória, pois há apenas uma troca de referências, e não de valores.

Foge um pouco da questão da pergunta, mas apenas para constar, note que as referências do PHP são num nível maior que os ponteiros de C, que são posições de memória. Independente disso, a troca de posição é pouco custosa em ambas as linguagens.

Sua solução, o XOR Swap é apenas para números:

```
$change_provider ^= $change_receiver ^= $change_provider ^= $change_receiver;
```

Ela se baseia em uma propriedade matemática do XOR:

> [Como funciona o algoritmo do Xor Swap?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/9497/70)

<sub>Como você já percebeu no seu teste, funciona com strings, mas apenas pelo fato delas serem tratadas como sequência de bytes, vide menção na resposta do @Omine</sub>

Comment: Sua solução é mais plausível até agora @Bacco. Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Dadas as condições, a forma mais adequada seria usando algorítmo XOR Swap. Ou seja, o mesmo que você apresentou na pergunta usando operadores bit a bit.

No entanto, para funcionar conforme o desejado, dentro do contexto da pergunta, precisa que **ambas as variáveis tenha a mesma quantidade de bytes**. Ou seja, pode usar strings e não somente valores numéricos. O que importa é a quantidade de bytes.

<sub>nota: O teste que apresentou na pergunta não retorna um bug. A variável com string maior é cortada por ser maior do que a outra variável.</sub>

Comment: Na verdade a definição de bug diz que é um mal funcionamento no sistema, nesse caso como o resultado não é o esperado pode ser considerado um bug. Você teria algum exemplo utilizando XOR Swap ?

Comment: Discordo, pois da forma como colocou retorna o resultado correto e não um bug. O bug em si poderia ser definido a nível de sistema mas não da operação do swap. Entendeu? Aliás, entendeu algo da resposta? rsrs  deixei bem claro que precisa  ter quantidade igual de bytes.. isso em si já explica o seu “bug”

Comment: Para deixar mais claro. Não tem solução dentro das condições que descreveu. Não tem mágica, a menos que as strings tenham a mesma quantidade de bytes e, mesmo assim, usando uma terceira variável é muito mais rápido e simples do que gambiarras com array ou bitwise operators.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug Você pode ler o primeiro paragrafo e ver que um resultado não desejado é sim um bug.

Comment: Mas obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: não é um bug...  não dentro do contexto do que apresentou....

Comment: Você pode pensar assim, porém meu quadro se enquadra da definição.

Comment: Se for considerar bug como quando o **resultado não é o esperado**, diversos operadores entrariam na lista. O Daniel explicou o motivo de não funcionar. Para funcionar é preciso que `ambas as variáveis tenham a mesma quantidade de bytes`, simples.

Comment: Completamente @PapaCharlie. O Daniel explicou o motivo do resultado não ser o esperado.  Mas isso não muda o fato de que o **resultado não é o esperado**. Logo é um bug.

Comment: rsrs  Ricardo, veja bem,  se eu fizer isso `$a = erf;` no php vai retornar um resultado inesperado. Quer dizer que isso é um bug do php?  rsrs  entende ?  é isso que está afirmando no uso do bitwise operator... está dizendo que é um bug no bitwise operator do php mas nao é...  e deixei claro que pode definir como bug  no funcionamento geral do seu script mas não que seja um bug desse recurso do php...  entendeu?  está a misturar as coisas...  e se quer tirar a prova, reporte isso no site do php como sendo bug e verá a resposta deles: http://bugs.php.net

Comment: Precisa de 2 variáveis com o mesmo tamanho e você usa tamanhos diferentes! O bug é realmente do PHP?

Comment: Acho que vocês estão confundindo erro de erro com bug. a definição de bug é extremamente clara: *A software bug is an error, flaw, failure or fault in a computer program or system that causes it to produce an incorrect or unexpected result, or to behave in unintended ways.* 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_bug

Comment: Está a interpretar de forma literal e desconsiderando o contexto aqui presente, Ricardo. Desculpe, mas não tenho mais o que dizer.